# .Net to Salesforce Integration

Tags: integration, scheduled-apex, wsdl, .net

I used EnterPrise WSDL for Salesforce integration. I was able to access the Account,Lead,Contacts, etc. objects. 
I need one help. Is it possible to get Apex Job Schedule from .Net?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access the scheduled jobs via the SOAP APIs using the [CronTrigger](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) object. With this you can check, among other things, the current State of the job, when it last started, and how many times it has been triggered.