# How to create UPSERT operation on CASE object in Salesforce using .NET

Tags: apex, webservices, .net

I went through following link , it says , you can access SF objects using EnterPrise WSDL in .NET.

[.Net to Salesforce Integration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32969/net-to-salesforce-integration)

My question is , what is the best method by which i can create and update CASE in Salesforce from my .NET application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Most common approach to this would be using SOAP APIs,
1. Create a enterprise WSDL from your org by going to - 
SEtup->Develop->API -> Generate Enterprise WSDL

1. Take the generated wsdl and add it as service reference in .NET project.
2. You will need to login to SF org using SOAP APIs and you will be able to access/create/update Case object from .NET application

below article explains in detail how this can be done.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications